# Error connecting to the remote server: Server '191.101.33.181' not found in known_hosts - Paramiko

Tags: ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys, tunnel

I can't figure out what's going on, I keep getting this error when I try to establish a tunnel to my VPS to send commands and receive it's output. I've got the VPS SSH keys, tried both "id_rsa" and "id_rsa.pub" but neither worked. What am I doing wrong? Also, if you spot anything else out then let me know!

```
import paramiko

from paramiko.client import SSHClient

def establish_ssh_tunnel():

    global tunnel

    # SSH connection details
    ssh_host = '***.***.**.***'
    ssh_port = 22
    ssh_username = '********'
    ssh_password = '*****************'

    # Local port to bind for tunnel
    local_port = 12345

    # Create SSH client
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("id_rsa")
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        # Connect to the remote server
        client.connect(ssh_host, ssh_port, ssh_username, ssh_password, pkey=key)

        # Open an SSH tunnel
        tunnel = client.get_transport().open_channel(
        "direct-tcpip",
        dest_addr=('localhost', local_port),
        src_addr=('localhost', 0)
        )

        print(f"SSH tunnel established. Listening on port {local_port}")

        # Wait for incoming commands on the tunnel
        while True:
        # Accept a command
            command = tunnel.recv(1024).decode().strip()

            if command == 'exit':
                break   

        # Process the command (replace with your logic)
        response = process_command(command)

        # Send the response back through the tunnel
        tunnel.send(response.encode())

            # Close the SSH tunnel and disconnect from the remote server
        if tunnel is not None:
            tunnel.close()
        client.close()
        print("SSH tunnel closed.")

    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print("Authentication failed. Please check your credentials.")
    except paramiko.SSHException as ssh_ex:
        print(f"Error connecting to the remote server: {ssh_ex}")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error: {ex}")



def process_command(command):
    if command == 'hello':
        return "Hello, world!"
    elif command == 'time':
        import datetime
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return str(now)
    else:
        return "Unknown command"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    establish_ssh_tunnel()
```